# Using OkHttp with Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, okhttp, stetho

The Google Cloud Endpoint generated [Android client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android) expects an HttpTransport, JsonFactory and HttpRequestInitializer as part of the generated Builder constructor (which extends from [AbstractGoogleJsonClient.Builder](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/json/AbstractGoogleJsonClient.Builder).  I want to use [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) to watch these network calls, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) to work with the generated client.

Has anyone successfully been able to use Stetho with Google Cloud Endpoints on Android (with or without OkHttp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps check this [Github issue](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/issues/227). There's also an [OkHttpTransport](https://github.com/julianshen/OkHttpTransport) that hasn't been modified in awhile, but the basis is, if you want to use OkHttp with the Java client, you can just extend `HttpTransport` to construct a request using OkHttp.

Comment: Thank you, I knew their had to be a way!! :-)